# indexing from 0 in vector in R

Tags: r

I have a vector

```
 E(graf)$weight
 [1] 0.36412384 0.57781546 0.18437357 0.93646406 0.20828406 0.17371658 0.08134196 0.90002920 0.58005694
[10] 0.45484858 0.36412384 0.57781546 0.18437357 0.93646406 0.20828406 0.17371658 0.08134196 0.90002920
[19] 0.58005694 0.45484858 0.36412384 0.57781546 0.18437357 0.93646406 0.20828406 0.17371658 0.08134196
[28] 0.90002920 0.58005694 0.45484858 0.36412384 0.57781546 0.18437357 0.93646406 0.20828406 0.17371658
[37] 0.08134196 0.90002920 0.58005694 0.45484858 0.36412384 0.57781546 0.18437357 0.93646406 0.20828406
[46] 0.17371658 0.08134196 0.90002920 0.58005694 0.45484858
```

How to index from 0 to 49, instead of 1 to 50?

Comment: It isn't clear what you mean. If `i` is a 0-based index then the corresponding entry would be `E(graf)$weight[i+1]`. Unlike some languages such as Visual Basic, R doesn't provide any way to directly change indexing to different starting bases, but it is easily enough to emulate it in software by adding or subtracting 1 from the index as needed.

Comment: I mean the random addition of values to E (graf), indexing from 0 to 49
E(graf)$weight <- runif (graf, min = 0, max = 1)

Answer (score 0):

R just like FORTRAN starts indexing from 1.
You cannot change the index R creates, but you can create your own index column associated with this vector:

```
id <- 0:(length(E(graph)$weight - 1)
```

If needed you can add this id vector to your R object and use it to subset your original vector, but you still will need to add 1 to id to subset i.